# ERROR: text search configuration does not exist

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I am trying to run a SQL query but it ends with `ERROR: text search configuration does not exist`.

How can I add a custom language text search option?

```
ERROR: text search configuration "czech" does not exist
LINE 88: ts_headline('czech', title, plainto_tsquery('czech', $1)...
```

Comment: Seems like you forgot to post the error.

Comment: Oh I am sorry, added it to main post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download this package: http://www.pgsql.cz/data/czech.tar.gz

Unzip and insert to: usr/pgsql-12/share/tsearch_data

Then run this as superuser:

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY cspell (template=ispell, dictfile = czech, afffile=czech, stopwords=czech);
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION cs (copy=english);
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION cs ALTER MAPPING FOR word, asciiword WITH cspell, simple;
```

Then you should be fine.

Source: https://postgres.cz/wiki/Instalace_PostgreSQL#Instalace_Fulltextu